# Request Last Update Date From Vanilla Forum

Tags: ios, restful-url

I have an iOS app that I would like to interface with an Vanilla forum in a very simple way. I would like the iOS app to request the last update date of the forum. That way I could indicate to the iOS app user the forum has been updated since their last visit.

I am guessing the way to go would be using Vanilla's REST services, but I am unsure of how to request the last update date, or if its even possible using REST.

I am studying information at this link: [Vanilla REST Services](http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/17525/vanilla-rest-services) and also searching through the PHP code to find something that might help.

Is there an easier way to do request the last update date of a Vanilla forum for use in an iOS app? If so, what is that easier way?

Comment: Is there simply an RSS/Atom feed you could use to capture the timestamp of the most recent post to the forum? Looks the the url to the rss feed should be http://yoursite/discussions/feed.rss

Comment: @Endophage: I have been testing this route. Unfortunately the RSS feed from Vanilla only gives the creation date of threads, not the last update date.  :-(

Comment: Ah, that's a rather poor implementation as the RSS standard defines a `<lastmod>` tag. Is Vanilla putting the creation time in the `lastmod` tag? That should probably be filed as a bug...